# How to insert integer and add value in database

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I would like to ask how can I make it an integer here is my code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String scoreValue = String.valueOf(scoreEdit);
    long val = adapter.insertDetails(scoreValue + 3);
    finish();
}
```

what I'm tryng to make is that everytime I click the button it will get the scoreValue and add 3 in it but when I put a number in the scoreValue like "2" it have "23" not "5" as I want it to be. I know it's about the String but when I change the

```
String scoreValue = String.valueOf(scoreEdit);
```

to

```
IntegerscoreValue = String.valueOf(scoreEdit);
```

I'm having an error can someone please help me please thanks

**EDITED:**

new code

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int scoreValue = Integer.parseInt(scoreEdit.getText().toString());
            long val = adapter.insertDetails(scoreValue + 3);
            finish();
        }
```

taken from

```
public long insertDetails(int score) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.SCORE, score);
    opnToWrite();
    long val = database_ob.insert(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, null,
            contentValues);
    Close();
    return val;
}
```

Comment: String.valueOf(ScoreEdit) tryes to parse ScoreEdit into String, what kind of data is scoreEdit ?

Comment: What is `scoreEdit`? getting value from edittext?

Comment: @Raghunandan - Yes it is getting value from edittext

Comment: @John where is that code of getting?

Comment: Edited my post it comes from the insertDetails

Answer (score 0):

use this, have to get string form EditText first

```
int scoreValue = Integer.parseInt(scoreEdit.getText().toString());
```

instead of

```
String scoreValue = String.valueOf(scoreEdit);
```

Comment: another problem is that I use that code and then it shows now an error "The method parseInt(String) in the type integer is not applicable for arguements(EditText)"

Comment: so you have to get string form EditText first, check updated answer now.

Comment: it still concatinates the values I put

Comment: check before inserting in db, what is the value. your passing to db

Comment: I inserted 2 and it gives me an output of 23 not 5 XD

Answer (score 0):

Chang to

```
try
   {
       int scoreValue = Integer.parseInt(scoreEdit);
   }
   catch(NumberFormatException ne)
   {
       ne.printStacktrace();
   }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Adding strings together will give you concatenation, but if you want to take the sum of two integers than convert the values to integer do the calculation AND THEN String.valueOf(x) will return the string value of the sum. Where X is the end sum of your result.